# JavaScript - Add values from array to nested object

Tags: javascript

I want to create a final object structure, as shown below.

```
let finalArr = {
    "friends": 
    [
        {
            "name": 'Jake',
            "friendsList": [
                "Friend1",
                "Friend2",
                "Friend3"
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

I start with this

```
let finalArr = {
      "friends": [
     ]
}
```

In a loop, I obtain data and store it into an Array, like this

```
[
  {
    name: 'Jake',
    friendsList: [
      'Friend1',
      'Friend2',
      'Friend3',
    ]
  },
```

How do I add the array I generate from the loop to the object, so that I can obtain the final structure that I want above? I tried `Json.push` but that doesn't seem to work, nor does a regular loop and plug, as that gives me out of bounds issues.

Comment: There is no JSON here. It is a POJO and what is `Json.push` ?

Comment: finalArr.friends.push(yourObject)

Comment: Oops, that was a mistake my bad. Meant `finalArr.friends.push` wasn't working, but its because I was doing something dumb

Answer (score 1):

You can access an object using bracket.

So, use `finalArr.friends.push` instead of `Json.push`

```
finalArr.friends.push({
    name: 'Jake',
    friendsList: [
      'Friend1',
      'Friend2',
      'Friend3',
    ]
  })
```

Comment: JSON is a STRING NOTATION format, you have an object

Comment: @mplungjan the object can be serialized as JSON.

Comment: @mplungjan Ah. Right. :)

Comment: @john Yes but that is irrelevant to the issues here

Answer (score 0):

simply you can push your object into friends array

```
let finalArr = {
  "friends": [
 ]
}
for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
finalArr.friends.push({
    name: 'Jake',
    friendsList: [
      'Friend1',
      'Friend2',
      'Friend3',
    ]
  })
}
```